# Unity recttransform normalized position to viewport ray between devices

Tags: unity-game-engine, normalize

I am trying to send a normalized position from one device to another so that I can translate from the recttransform on desktop to the viewport on mobile.

I had some troubles with the pivot of the object so tried to take it into the calculation, basically the goal of this is so that the middle is always 0.5, 0.5 and the bottom left is 0,0. Or maybe this is not correct?

Anyway, something goes wrong. The further I go away from the middle of recttransform's middle the bigger the offset becomes?

```
private Vector2 getNormalizedScreenspacePoint(PointerEventData pointerEventData) {
     //Get local mouse position within rectangle
     Vector2 localMousePosition = default;
     RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(imageRectTransform, pointerEventData.position, pointerEventData.pressEventCamera, out localMousePosition);
    
     //Get point within rect in relation to pivot with 0,0 being bottom left
     Vector2 pointWithinRect = new Vector2(
          localMousePosition.x + (imageRectTransform.rect.width * imageRectTransform.pivot.x),
          localMousePosition.y + (imageRectTransform.rect.height * imageRectTransform.pivot.y));
    
     Vector2 normalizedScreenspacePoint = new Vector2(
          (pointWithinRect.x / imageRectTransform.rect.width),
          (pointWithinRect.y / imageRectTransform.rect.height)
     );
    
          return normalizedScreenspacePoint;
     }


public Vector2 getScreenSpacePoint(Vector2 normalizedScreenspacePoint)
{
    float x = objectPlacementCamera.pixelWidth * normalizedScreenspacePoint.x;
    float y = objectPlacementCamera.pixelHeight * normalizedScreenspacePoint.y;

    Vector2 screenSpacePoint = new Vector2(x, y);
    return screenSpacePoint;
}

public Ray getViewportRay(Vector2 normalizedScreenspacePoint)
{
    Vector2 screenSpacePoint = getScreenSpacePoint(normalizedScreenspacePoint);
    Vector3 viewPortPoint = objectPlacementCamera.ScreenToViewportPoint(screenSpacePoint);
    Ray ray = objectPlacementCamera.ViewportPointToRay(viewPortPoint);
    return ray;
}
```

I am not sure yet if it's going wrong on the sending or the receiving side...

Comment: Why not just transmitting the Viewport point which is already normalized between 0 and 1 ?

Comment: What do you mean? The recttransform on the desktop is not scaled to match the viewport, if the mobile streamed frames are portrait the rect is rescaled to fit landscape.

Comment: Yeah but what is the difference between e.g. `getScreenSpacePoint` and simply using e.g. [`ViewportPointToRay`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ViewportPointToRay.html) which already takes a normalized position between 0,0 and 1,1?

Comment: A yeah sure I replaced my functions with the unity functions, but it seems there is still something wrong in my getNormalizedScreenspacePoint function